# Identical binary fields are different in a byte[]

Tags: c#, sql, reflection

I am having trouble storing `VARBINARY(MAX)` data in a `SQL` table.

```
SELECT BulkColumn
FROM    OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Example.exe', SINGLE_BLOB) MyFile
```

I populate a table by doing the above - because the `Binary` strings are so long, we can't do a direct insert of a string so we use the `chunking` method, whereby you do an initial insert and follow up with a series of update statements.

By using the first method to populate a row with the binary data and then executing the script to populate another row with binary data.

If I copy and paste the contents of the binary field and compare the two - they are identical.

If I use the following code however, they aren't:

```
byte[] arr1 = null;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SippPremium"].ConnectionString))
{
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT BinaryData FROM dbo.vertDLL WHERE DLL_PK = 1", con))
  {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    sda.Fill(dt);
    arr1 = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["BinaryData"];
  }
}
//Same code to get arr2
for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
{
  if (i > arr2.Length)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Array finishes at {0}", arr2[i - 1]);
  }
  else if(arr1[i] !=  arr2[i])
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Byte {0} is different", i);
    Console.ReadLine();
    break;
  }
}
```

The length of `arr1` is `2423168` and `arr2` is `1211584`, for some reason - perfectly half. I have done this with 113 other assembly files, this is the only one that doesn't work properly.

I am driving myself round the bend trying to figure out what is wrong, any ideas?

Comment: What is `arr2`, and how is it read?

Comment: if i understand correctly you try to compare binary fields from 2 different rows. and they a different. Thats right?

Comment: Please show how `arr2` is populated. Also, the "Array finishes at {0}" message seems to be reporting the byte value at `arr[1-i]`, rather than the value of the index `i` (or `i-1`). And shouldn't the comparison of `arr1.Length` and `arr2.Length` take place outside of the `for` loop? Finally, which message are you seeing, "Array finishes at {0}" or "Byte {0} is different"?

Comment: @Iridium please see the `//` where I state that the same code is used to get `arr2`, I just didn't include it to shorten up the length of my question.

Comment: If you are using identical code to populate `arr2`, then it should be identical to `arr1`, and the fact that it isn't suggests that either the code isn't the same, or something is changing in the DB between the two calls. Neither of which we can reliably determine from the code you've provided. Also don't really see why you're populating a `DataTable` in order to pull out a single field. Why not just use `cmd.ExecuteScalar()`?

Comment: @Iridium the only difference is the way a populate the two tables, 1. direct insert of the binary and two a SQL script generated by Redgate Data Compare to insert the data, the SQL string representative is the same however the binary is different somehow... The only way I can give you more information than what I have given is to post a 7mb file into the question

Comment: In which case you need to show the *actual code* (SQL, script, etc...) that's used to populate the tables. Just giving descriptions of what your code does is very unlikely to enable anyone to diagnose your problem.

Comment: @Iridium that's fine, where can I put the script for you to see? I certainly can't fit it inside my question.

Comment: The code you post should be a succinct as possible whilst still exhibiting the issue you're asking about, so if it's as big as you say you'll need to cut it down. (There's also a decent chance that in doing so you'll discover what the problem is on your own).